# Buffered Reader for Android Streaming from Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, stream, arduino

Hey guys so I'm trying to read a stream from a bluetooth device continuously streaming integers like this:

```
-11
121
123
1234
-11
```

I have everything working with some code I found online, but to do some of the processing the numbers need to be ints as opposed to Strings, parseInt is taking up too much CPU, and I tried using a buffered stream with no avail.

Here is the current method:

```
 void beginListenForData()
        {
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
  final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {                
               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
               {
                    try 
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            myLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
               }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }
```

If it makes a difference, the data is coming from an Arudino, which I can modify the way it streams.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DataInputStream` wrapped around a `BufferedInputStream`, and the `readInt()` method. This assumes network byte order in the integers of course.

Forget all this `arraycopy()` stuff.

Comment: I tried using this:
    
       final BufferedInputStream inputStream = new       BufferedInputStream(mmInputStream);
        final DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream); Still nothing showing up