# How to receive a complete arduino string in android

Tags: android, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am doing an app for my arduino sensor I wanted to know how to actually obtain the data from arduino to android studio via bluetooth because in my arduino I put `Serial.println("occupied")` but when receive in android it somehow mixed with some numbers/bytes like "o2cuppied" or else it will receive seperately in logcat. I don't know what is wrong with it.

Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  serial1.begin(9600); //for the bluetooth module
}
void loop() {
 
  //send data to Bluetooth module//
  if (dist[0] < dist_threshold) {
    serial1.print("Occupied\n");
   
  }
 if (dist[1] < dist_threshold) {
    
    serial1.print("Occupied2\n");
    
  }
```

Android

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

                switch (msg.what) {
                    case RECEIVE_MESSAGE:                             // if receive massage
                        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);   // create string from bytes array
                                                     // and clear
                            txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + strIncom);

                            break;
                }
            }
        };
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            bluetoothSocket = socket;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                    h.obtainMessage(RECEIVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget(); // Send to message queue Handler
                   
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Logcat

> 2019-11-27 12:28:13.505 12733-12893/com.example.fyp D/MainActivity: InputStream: O
>
> 2019-11-27 12:28:13.508 12733-12893/com.example.fyp D/MainActivity: InputStream: ccupied

Answer (score 0):

```
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1); // create string from bytes array
                sb.append(strIncom);                                      // append string
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                  // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                 // if end-of-line,
                    sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);            // extract string
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                    final String finalSbprint = sbprint;
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP: You have to concatenate the incoming bytes.

But if the Arduino is only going to send text you can make your life easier by letting it send "Occupied\n" instead of "Occupied".

On the receiving side you add a BufferedStreamReader and use its readLine() member to read that line.

Comment: is it something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913546/buffered-reader-for-android-streaming-from-bluetooth

Comment: or do you have any example?

Comment: There are examples all over the internet and on this site. So a bit of googling will help.